# Different definitions of ring and field.

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

From Hanh and Rosenthal "Set functions" (1948, p.3):

1. A system of sets which is closed with respect to addition and intersection is called a **ring**.
2. A system of sets which is closed with respect to addition and subtraction is called a **field**.

*And by "addition" I understand "union".*

From Taylor "Introduction to measure and integration" (digital printed version, 2008, p.15):

1. ...we see that a **ring** is a class of sets closed under the operations of union, intersection, and difference and...
2. Thus a ring is a **field** if and only if it is closed under the operation of taking the complement.

Very different definitions for me. I know that a ring (or field) in the algebra and in the set theory has different definitions (I am not sure). But here in both cases we talk about a class of sets.

Question: what is going wrong? Maybe the last too definitions are more modern? Or there are some problems in my understanding?

Comment: You're certainly correct that the two pairs of definitions seem different. For example, $\big\{ \{1\},\{1,2\}\big\}$ is a ring according to Hanh/Rosenthal but not according to Taylor. If "subtraction" means "set difference", then whether a set is a field in the Hanh/Rosenthal sense does not depend upon the universe in which the set elements live, but it does in the Taylor sense since the complement is invoked.

Comment: There is no fixed terminology: these types of classes of sets arose when trying to generalize Lebesgue measure. The two definitions indeed describe different objects. In the former set of definitions, the whole set need not belong to either rings or fields, in the latter it must belong to fields.